# Exit US and re-enter Canada as a Canadian Permanent Resident with South Korean passport

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, legal, canadian-residents

I'm a Korean(South) who obtained a Canadian PR status 4 months ago and have a H4 visa on my Korean passport to stay in US legally.
Recently, I moved down to US with my husband since he got a job here.
My husband is Canadian citizen and have a H1B visa in US.
We are visiting Canada for a short trip next week and I need a Canadian PR Card or Permanent Resident Travel Document to re-enter Canada. 
However, the problem is that I haven't received my Canadian PR card yet and there is not enough time to get a Permanent Resident Travel Document from Canadian visa office.
So, I'm planning to surrender all of the other documents that can prove my Canadian PR status and exit US to go to Canada by air.

Is there any possibility that I get denied to leave US for Canada or to enter Canada?
Do I and my husband go through the same immigration check together when we exit US?

Comment: Are you travelling by air or land?

Comment: Have you 'landed', i.e. [validated your confirmation of Permanent Residence Status](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=748&top=22) at a border or PR office?

Comment: "Do I and my husband go through the same immigration check together when we exit US?": The US has no exit immigration check other than that performed administratively by the airline.  The airline would deny boarding if they determine that you do not have the proper documentation for Canada.  Traveling and checking in with your husband is unlikely to affect their determination on that matter.

Answer (score 1):

The [official](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/newcomers/about-pr.asp) quote:

> If you travel outside Canada, the PR card is your proof that you are a permanent resident of Canada. If you leave Canada, you will need this card to re-enter the country on a commercial vehicle, like an airplane, boat, train or bus.

I have crossed the Canadian border on a bus multiple times in 2008 fall without a PR card because my PR card was sent to the wrong address. But even the official word says if you drive a car you are good.

Answer (score 1):

When you are entering Canada, Canada doesn't care what visa you are on in US, it only cares about your Canadian papers. When you are entering US doesn't care what your Canadian status is, it only cares about your US papers.

If you are entering Canada by air, boat, bus, you need valid Canadian papers to board the commercial vehicle. If you are driving across in your own vehicle, you can show your CoPR and get in (might take longer at the border while they verify your status).

If you decide to fly and don't have any Canadian papers, **you will not be allowed** to board the plane. Remember that the airline has no way to verify your canadian status since they don't have access to CBSA database, unlike the officers at road crossings who do. I've flown several times from US-Canada and they DO check for papers.

While coming back to US, you need to have a stamped valid H1B visa on passport since that is your US status currently.

I would recommend applying for a PRTD if you haven't already; takes only a week to get it.